# How can I stop Android to capture KEYCODE_F2 and KEY_CODE_F4?

Tags: android

I am trying to capture all keys on the hardware keyboard available on the device. This device comes with Function keys (at least I can map the hardware keys to fire F2 and F4).

Every time F2 or F4 is pressed, the device uses the system functions assigned to these keys. For F2 it suspends (sleep) the device and F4 shows the app switcher screen.

I can get all other function keys from F1 to F10 except those F2 and F4.

```
adb shell getevent -lt /dev/input/event4

    [    1141.537066] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000000
    [    1141.537096] EV_KEY       KEY_F1               DOWN
    [    1141.537096] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1141.752672] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000000
    [    1141.752672] EV_KEY       KEY_F1               UP
    [    1141.752703] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1143.004565] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000001
    [    1143.004565] EV_KEY       KEY_F2               DOWN
    [    1143.004595] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1143.202959] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000001
    [    1143.202990] EV_KEY       KEY_F2               UP
    [    1143.202990] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1144.610461] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000002
    [    1144.610461] EV_KEY       KEY_F3               DOWN
    [    1144.610491] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1144.808031] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000002
    [    1144.808031] EV_KEY       KEY_F3               UP
    [    1144.808062] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1146.466601] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000003
    [    1146.466631] EV_KEY       KEY_F4               DOWN
    [    1146.466631] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
    [    1146.670946] EV_MSC       MSC_SCAN             00000003
    [    1146.670977] EV_KEY       KEY_F4               UP
    [    1146.670977] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

On windows mobile 6 devices, many F Keys have this issue but can easily solved by using AllKeys(True) from the WM SDK.

The keys are generated correctly, as I can see with adb shell getvent...

What do I have to code in an Android Java application to get the F2 and F4?

Update: Code (although standard)

```
    edit1.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            return  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
            String action = "onKeyDown";

            final String message = "[KeyEvent, {name:" + name +
                    "},{action:" + action +
                    "},{code:" + String.valueOf(keyCode) +
                    "},{chars:" + event.getCharacters() +
                    "},{char:" + event.getUnicodeChar() +
                    "},{scode:" + event.getScanCode() +
                    "}]";
            Log.d(TAG, message);
            addLog(message);
            return false;
        }
```

Full test code at https://github.com/hjgode/KeyTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/e841719/keytest/KeyTest.java

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: added a small code sample

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the device's OEM implementation of remapping hardware keys to other keys.

It looks like incoming hardware key event KEY_F2 is translated to KEY_SLEEP before it is delivered to the android app.

This has to be fixed by the OEM vendor of the device.

I tested with another device which has a keypad with native function keys and these are recognized as KEYCODE_F2 etc. by the application. On the hardware side, getevent shows the same KEY_F2 code as on the device that has no native F2 key on the keypad, but a hardware key has been mapped to F2 by the OEM provided function (uses PS/2 keycodes).